# Why am I getting this error in my bash shell scipt

Tags: linux, git, bash

I been trying to add a option to my bash shell script that is someone does a "-r" I do a push to a git server but I am getting the following error

```
mirror.sh: line 8: conditional binary operator expected
mirror.sh: line 8: syntax error near `-e'
mirror.sh: line 8: `if [[ "$1" -e "-r" ]];then'
```

below is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/joe/Documents/sourcecode/mirror.git
git svn rebase

#
# if option -r then push to master
#
if [[ "$1" -e "-r" ]];then
    git push origin master
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about:

```
if [[ "$1" == "-r" ]]; then
```

?

-e in your example tests if a file exists. which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`if [[ "$1" = "-r" ]];then`

or

`if [[ "$1" == "-r" ]];then`

Comment: -eq is aritmetic comparison between integers, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

As stated `-e` is indeed a [file existence test](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html). I guess you wanted to compare values and thought of using `-eq` but that is a [arithmetic binary operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions). You need `==` to compare strings as

```
if [[ "$1" == "-r" ]];
```